# ServiceStack SQLITE_LOCKED

Tags: c#, sqlite, servicestack

I get some troubles with my sqlite database, I get SQLITE_LOCKED and SQLITE_BUSY when I try to insert data, but not every time it's quite random.
Shall I close my connection after each database transactions? Thanks

Comment: Just wrap your updates in `IsolationLevel.Serializable` transactions. Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to lock write access as Sqlite supports multiple concurrent readers but only 1 concurrent writer.